# What's the standard duration for turnstile page animation on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, transition

I'm displaying a control that pretends to be a page, and I'm wondering how long my turnstile-type transition should take so that it fits in with the rest of the system. How long do normal turnstile page transitions take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the Storyboard for the Turnstile transition in the Toolkit on Codeplex, here's [TurnstileForwardIn.xaml](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620#1349610).

From a quick glance it looks like 350ms.